# Which is the connection string for ArangoDB .NET driver when password is empty?

Tags: .net, arangodb

Both this

`Arango.Client.ASettings.AddConnection("conn", "127.0.0.1", 8529, false, "user_name", "");`

and this

`Arango.Client.ASettings.AddConnection("conn", "127.0.0.1", 8529, false, "user_name", null);`

will bring to error

`"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."`

for any further access.

Comment: which .NET driver?

Comment: @AndrewGrothe
ArangoDB-NET

https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/Cookbook/Administration/Authentication.html) you will find that using an empty password is only possible when Authentication is turned off.

> Authentication is turned on by default in ArangoDB. You should make
>   sure that it was not turned off manually however. Check the
>   configuration file (normally named /etc/arangodb.conf) and make sure
>   it contains the following line in the server section:
>
> ```
> authentication = true
> ```

To the best of my knowledge you have two options, turn off authentication or provide a password.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that.